# If second derivative of a function is constant, you can bound the maximum of this function's absolute value in terms of this constant

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inequality, upper-lower-bounds

> If the second derivative of a function is constant on some interval, you can bound the maximum of this function's absolute value from below in terms of this constant.

What does the above statement mean?

If $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c\implies f''(x)=2a$

Does the above statement mean $|f(x)|\ge2a?$

My main intention is to understand the answer posted on [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1704636/prove-that-abc-le17-if-ax2bxc-le1-for-0-le-x-le1).

Comment: For $f(x) = x^2$, $a=1$ but $|f(0)| = 0 < 2= 2a$, so your claim is false. Also, its absolute value is unbounded so there is no maximum value.

Comment: It says "in terms of this constant", no "by this constant".